# Firestore AttributeError: module 'firebase_admin' has no attribute 'firestore'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I encountered a problem when importing the Firestore module from package firebase_admin.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()  

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
  'projectId': "...",
})

db = firebase_admin.firestore.client()
```

i installed the firebase_admin package using:

```
pip install --upgrade firebase-admin
```

But it returned:

```
AttributeError: module 'firebase_admin' has no attribute 'firestore'
```

I wonder if i missed something.

Answer (score 10):

faced the same issue, adding the following import worked for me

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

Answer (score 0):

The import part is correct. You did the import of the library and resources correctly.

However, the part of the `db = firebase_admin.firestore.client()` it's not completely well set. This method needs a parameter for it to be called correctly. As it's explained in the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.firestore):

> Parameters: app – An App instance (optional)

So, even if you don't to send a specific app, you need to set it as `none`, for the method to be called correctly. Another example of how to call the method can be found in the official repository from Firebase, accessible via [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/firebase_admin/firestore.py).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: you don't need to set a method parameter to its default value. look at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/firebase_admin/firestore.py

Comment: the AttribteError is related to an import error not a method invocation one

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
firebase_admin.firestore
```

but you can use

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

Hope this helps !